# Pagination in Grails

Tags: grails, pagination

I want to add some pagination stuff to my grails app. I have the list action and in it I did this:

```
if(!params.max){
params.max = 3
}
    def query = Profile.where {
        userType == "F"
    }
    def freelancers = query.list(sort:"firstName", max:params.max)
    if(freelancers) {
        def freelancersCount = query.count()
        return[freelancer:freelancers, fCount:freelancersCount]
    } else {
        response.sendError(404)
    }
```

in gsp I wrote this:

```
<div id="paginate">
    <g:paginate controller="freelancers" action="list" total="${fCount}"/>
</div>
```

everything is ok, a have a 5 objects in my db and i can see only 3 when open a gsp page in browser, but when I click on the Next to open other 2 object, I see the same 3 ones. what is wrong and what I must to do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to pass the offset into your call to [list](http://grails.org/doc/1.3.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/list.html):

```
def freelancers = query.list(sort:"firstName", offset:params.offset, 
max:params.max)
```

Comment: thank u, it's working. but can I use some css styles to the g:paginate tag and how?

Comment: @Jack: yes, view the source to check out the classes that grails puts on the html, and use those classes for your selectors. (either that or hack on main.css)

Answer (score 1):

1)  If you are using Criteria query then :

```
 params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)
 Integer offset = params.offset as Integer ?: 0
 List userInstanceList = User.createCriteria().list(max:params.max,offset:offset) {
            or {
                ilike('name', "%${name}%")
                ilike('email', "%${email}%")
            }
            order('dateCreated', 'desc')
        }
```

2) If you are using GORM query then :

```
 params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)
 Integer offset = params.offset as Integer ?: 0
 List<User> userList=User.list(max:params.max,offset:offset)
```